# What is the meaning of the highlighted expression ?

Tags: physics

[image]

I am using GRQUICK package for calculation of Ricci tensors. I am using a non diagonal metric with coefficients being functions of two co-ordinates. I want to know if the highlighted expression denotes partial derivates or something entirely different.

Comment: It represents derivative of `v[r,theta]` w.r.t `theta` once.

Comment: You can caopy and paste and use `FullForm` to check what is there.

Comment: Thanks !! **v[r,theta]** w.r.t **theta** once.. Could you tell me the logic to understand that ? r corresponds to 1 while theta corresponds to 2. For example what would you make of v(2,0) term similarly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to see [help](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html) on `D`.

```
D[v[r, t], t]  (*it gives partial derivative of v w.r.t t once*)
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Here the superscript `(0,1)` means that `v[r,t]` is partially differentiated once w.r.t `t` thats why you have 1 on right side because in the argument `[r, t]`, `t` is on the right side.

Now, if you want to differentiate `v` w.r.t `r`, then

```
D[v[r, t], r]  (*it gives partial derivative of v w.r.t r once*)
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
D[D[v[r, t], r], r]  (*it gives partial derivative of v w.r.t r twice*)
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes ! Many thanks. Now its crystal clear :-)

Comment: @AravindRavi Happy to help.